# ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG for ImageView within layout?

Tags: android, antialiasing

Does anyone know how to apply the `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` to `ImageView`'s in layouts rather than in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to apply the attribute `android:antialias="true"`, like so:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:antialias="true" />
```

Comment: android:antialias don't apply to the imageView!

Comment: @Pablo, 2 years ago when this was answered it certainly did. Hence the OPs thankful comment and the up-votes from other users. But yeah. Thanks for pointing out that it was removed from the API nearly 2 years after the fact.

Comment: So, what's the solution today (in 2013)?

Answer (score 4):

2013-year-way: declare special xml resource describing ImageView's content. For example we want an ImageView to contain antialiased Bitmap. So we need to write somethig like this:

```
<bitmap 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_draggable_item"/>
```

Comment: Ugh.  This is the annoying kind of API change.